# How do you report group history? (audience growth/change)

Tags: civimail, groups, reports, unsubscribe, subscribe

We transitioned from MailChimp to Mosaico - overall is been okay - but there is a report we were asked to generate that I can't seem to figure out. The report would display group size over time (monthly preferred). This way we can visually demonstrate growth or decline over any time period. Is there a way we can do this?

Somewhat related: How many new subscriptions (added to group) since last mailing to group. (I can do the math - but it would be nice if it was a report so I can have it on their dashboards.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this [Group Growth extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/groupgrowth)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Its so pretty. thank you.

Comment: If there is an update - it would also be nice to see the raw numbers in a chart - mouse over works for now. Also ability to filter by contacts with emails and not on hold.

Thank you again!

Comment: Feel free to suggest this on the [issue queue](https://lab.civicrm.org/artfulrobot/groupgrowth/issues) - that way you'll get notified if/when the feature is implemented. Nb. if you hover your mouse over any of the chunks, it will say like "Loss: 5" or "Retained: 23" etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below two extension and modify as per your needs

https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/mailingsubscriptions

https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/subscriptionhistory

Comment: Neither of those seem to do it. I can't group by month for example - I can only do per contact. I also can't filter out contacts in the trash on either of them - which is weird.

Comment: You won't find the exact requirement you are looking for, the above extensions are being contributed so that it can used by community, these extension were developed with minimum features based on their client requirement and budget. You will need alter this extension or create your own using as reference from the above extension to generate a report that you wish to have with filters, columns etc

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact needs, the [Historic Membership Data](https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.historicmembershipdata) extension may also be helpful.